# Building a Rails Api service issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rails-api

I am building a rails api service and i started with rails-api gem and devise gem for user authentication, i also rolled out my own versioning, the excellent [RailsCast on Versioning APIs](http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning) was all i needed.

Now here are some of the issues i'm facing

- First, though rails-api gem removes all modules that would not be necessary, i was expecting the errors returned to be in an api format, and then the main exception logged instead because right now if i should even use curl to make a request and it fails because of routing or other reasons, the entire error stack is returned in the form of html css with some javascript and i'm pretty much sure that is not what i want to return to my api consumers.

So my question is, how do i handle all errors properly in a rails-api and not return the long error stack.

- Secondly, how do i get rails generator to automatically create all new controllers under the namespace i specified in the route (I see this to me impractical but hey, i'm just asking :P)
- Also can anybody point to me to other neccessary resources i could use in building a successful rails api service.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Some resources:

- [Api with Rails Metal](http://www.slideshare.net/artellectual/developing-api-with-rails-metal)
- [Building a Tested, Documented and Versioned JSON API Using Rails 4](http://www.emilsoman.com/blog/2013/05/18/building-a-tested/)
- [API error codes](http://apiux.com/2013/03/28/2-steps-api-error-codes/)
- [Building a Platform API on Rails](http://blog.thecodepath.com/2011/06/27/building-a-platform-api-on-rails/)
- [API with Ruby on Rails: useful tricks](http://railsware.com/blog/2013/04/08/api-with-ruby-on-rails-useful-tricks/)

Answer (score 1):

I use [ActiveModel::Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) for my APIs.

I like to just render the errors inside the controller actions:

```
# almost pseudocode
unless request_successful?
  render json: { errors: { model: [ t(:your_request_made_no_sense, scope: :model)] } }, status: :bad_request
end
```

If you're interested in reading up on a pretty elegant way of doing APIs, you might have a look at [this 2beards article](http://2beards.net/2012/03/what-the-hell-is-a-hypermedia-api-and-why-should-i-care/), which is a good intro has a lot of links to great resources.